# Join On 1 to N mapped columns

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 tables here namely

EMPLOYEE_DETAILS:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| EMP_ID  | AREA_CODE   | SECTOR_CODE  |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 1223    | 5001        | 1001         |
| 3224    | 6001        | 2001         |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

LOCATION_DETAILS:

```
+------+---------------+
| ID   | LOCATION_NAME |
+------+---------------+
| 1001 | SECTOR 1      |
| 2001 | SECTOR 2      |
| 5001 | AREA 1        |
| 6001 | AREA 2        |
+------+---------------+
```

Columns `AREA_CODE` & `SECTOR_CODE` of `EMPLOYEE_DETAILS` references column `ID` of `LOCATION_DETAILS` table logically. There are no physical foreign key constraints among the 2.

I'm trying to get the `AREA_NAME` & `SECTOR_NAME` of each `EMP_ID`.

Expected Output:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| EMP_ID  | AREA_NAME   | SECTOR_NAME  |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 1223    | AREA 1      | SECTOR 1     |
| 3224    | AREA 2      | SECTOR 2     |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Is there any way to achieve this via a join query? Many Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the same table twice with different alias names

```
select e.emp_id, 
       a.LOCATION_NAME as area,
       s.LOCATION_NAME as sector
from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS e
join LOCATION_DETAILS a on a.id = e.AREA_CODE   
join LOCATION_DETAILS s on s.id = e.SECTOR_CODE
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the assist. Wasn't aware this was allowed.