# Special Join On 1 to N mapped columns

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union

This question is an extension of AJC's [Join On 1 to N mapped columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156342/join-on-1-to-n-mapped-columns).

What if `EMPLOYEE_DETAILS` is like this:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| EMP_ID  | AREA_CODE   | SECTOR_CODE  |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 1223    | 5001        | 1001         |
| 3224    | (NULL)      | 2001         |
| 3225    | 6001        | (NULL)       |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Then how would it be possible to map the respective names like this output:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| EMP_ID  | AREA_NAME   | SECTOR_NAME  |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 1223    | AREA 1      | SECTOR 1     |
| 3224    | (NULL)      | SECTOR 2     |
| 3225    | AREA 2      | (NULL)       |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

I thought about doing a `union of joins` like so,

```
select e.emp_id, a.LOCATION_NAME as area, s.LOCATION_NAME as sector
from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS e 
join LOCATION_DETAILS a on a.id = e.AREA_CODE 
join LOCATION_DETAILS s on s.id = e.SECTOR_CODE 

union 
select e.emp_id, a.LOCATION_NAME as area, NULL as sector 
from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS e 
join LOCATION_DETAILS a on a.id = e.AREA_CODE 

union 
select e.emp_id, NULL as area, s.LOCATION_NAME as sector 
from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS e 
join LOCATION_DETAILS s on s.id = e.SECTOR_CODE;
```

But then this would require me to use this as an internal query to get the expected result.

Is there a more concise way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `left join` twice?

```
select e.emp_id, a.location_name as area, s.location_name as sector 
from employee_details e 
left join location_details a on a.id = e.area_code 
left join location_details s on s.id = e.sector_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I can advice solution with single join like:

```
select 
    e.emp_id, 
    group_concat(if(ld.id = e.area_code, ld.location_name, null)) as area, 
    group_concat(if(ld.id = e.sector_code, ld.location_name, null)) as sector 
from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS e 
left join LOCATION_DETAILS ld 
   on (ld.id = e.area_code or ld.id = e.sector_code)
group by e.emp_id;
```

Here the fiddle: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0c2a07647455f899fd07e2b91ad9e588&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)